# Decimal to Int Converter

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to make a Conversion, to convert Decimal to Int. Look at my code:

```
<ProgressBar Margin="0,10,0,10" 
    Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsIndeterminate="False" Height="10"
    Maximum="{Binding SavingGoal, Converter={StaticResource DecimalToInt}}" Value="{Binding Balance, Converter={StaticResource DecimalToInt}}"/>
```

And here it's where the bindings pointing at:

```
newGoal.SavingGoal = Convert.ToDecimal(SavingsAmountsTextBox.Text);
newGoal.Balance = 0;
```

And here is the class:

```
public decimal SavingGoal { get; set; }
public decimal Balance { get; set; }
```

So my problem is that I don't know how to use IValueConverter to fit in my case. I want to convert the decimal that my UserControl is parsing to int and make the progressbar finally to work.

Comment: Can you show your `DeciamlToInt` converter?

Comment: Your converter would need to be passed the savings goal as well as the balance. The IValueConverter interface does specify a parameter, but it may be more straight forward to add a "derived property" that does the calculation. Something like `public int PercentOfGoal { get { return (int)(Balance/SavingsGoal) * 100; } }`, and then bind `Value` to that.

Comment: In the time I didn't have anything on my Converter. Right now I did something like this in the Convert method:

`if (value is decimal){
      return System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
return false;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you realy need a decimal? The Maximum property and the Value property are doubles, so if this project is about money just use double. If you don't need more than 16 digits after comma, a double makes more sence.

If you still want to convert with a Converter convert it in the Convert()-Method of your Converter Class

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    decimal x = (decimal)value;
    return Decimal.ToInt32(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your `DecimalToInt` converter as a static resource

```
<ns:DecimalToIntConverter x:Key="DecimalToInt" />
```

And then implement it

```
public class DecimalToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // convert here
        // value is your binding - use it if you can
        // parameter is the additional parameter that you can pass in but don't need to.
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value; // who cares?
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have registered my Converter as a static resource. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want truncate or round for the decimals? If you are ok with rounding,
you don't need a converter for this. You can do it using the StringFormat parameter on the binding. If you use a string format of # it will round.

Comment: I tried it with StringFormat parameter but it didn't work on my case due to other problems in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it better to check first if it's really decimal? I mean something like that:

`if (value is decimal){
     return System.Convert.toInt32(value);
}
return false;`